# How to deal with DataTypes in a wrapped class

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, adapter, wrapper, decorator

following situation where I have no clue how to do it right:

My C#-Application has a **ClassA** that I have to extend with some functions. This is done with **ClassB**, that references **ClassA** and "wraps", "decorates", "adapts" (or whatever pattern it is) the class.
My **ClassA** defines some datatypes that **ClassB** uses and has public for others.

So if my **ClassC** wants to reference the **ClassB** it also has to reference **ClassA** because it has the definition for the Types.

I don't think that is right: when I wrap around a class, another class that uses the wrapper class should not know anything about the wrapped class.

I could just copy-paste the types in the **ClassB** but if something changes, I would have to do it twice and I don't think that's right.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Thanks a lot,
Joerg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Whatever pattern" you choose is important for this matter since it will shape your design;) 
Since it seems you'd like to **hide** ClassA's interface, [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) pattern would be relevant. (With the [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern, ClassB would also subclass ClassA, resulting in the same datatypes exposed by ClassA to be exposed also by ClassB.)

Now back to the question:

It seems you don't have a perfect solution. Let's call the datatype in ClassA **TypeA**, and ClassB **TypeB**. Either you will reuse TypeA for TypeB and create a dependency between the two, or make TypeB completely independent and repeat yourself.

If you have compelling reasons to decouple **ClassA** completely from the rest of the system, you can make TypeA independent. It will violate *DRY*, but your clients will not be affected if ClassA belongs to a 3rd party and they decide to change its interface.

It might be an overkill in less compelling cases though. If you own the code for ClassA, you might then put TypeA outside ClassA so that all other clients use it without (directly) depending to ClassA.

Comment: In my case I have the responsibility for code in ClassA and ClassB (at least right now). So if I put the definition of TypeA outside of ClassA but still have it in my assembly/project, I still have to reference this assembly from the assembly where ClassC resides. This means I would have to use a single project (let's call it "MyTypeLib") that has to be referenced by all the other projects?

Comment: Another question: you mention a dependency between the two types. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @joerg Q1: I think which assembly to put it into is another aspect of the problem. It's suggested to put in the same assembly the units that change together (ref: Uncle Bob). If TypeA changed, ClassA and ClassB would also change, so all these classes should be in the same assembly if one is to follow that advice.

Comment: Q2: What I had in mind was TypeB inheriting TypeA so that the fields would not be repeated. In effect, though, I guess that would be equivalent to using TypeA again.

Comment: Thanks so far for your answers. It seems that I got the base principles but the point where I struggle is the management of the assemblies, means: what belongs where? Do you have a suggestion where I can find some literature/tutorial/... to this topic? You find a lot about classes, patterns, architecture but I it seems to be difficult to have something that focuses on the assembly-management.

Comment: Sure, here's the link to the reference in my comment above: http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/granularity.pdf. There's a lot about packaging there, especially "The Reuse/Release Equivalence Principle" section where "the granule of reuse is the granule of release" motto is explained.